# Options to generate per-device SAS tokens

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am going through the following article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-sas?tabs=node#sas-tokens

... and I understand that I have the following options to generate a per device SAS token:

- **Azure CLI**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-hub-generate-sas-token
- **Azure IoT tools for Visual Studio Code**: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-tools

Other than above two options, are there any other way(s) to generate per-device SAS connection strings?

Is there any way to generate per-device SAS tokens in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Other than above two options, are there any other way(s) to generate per-device SAS connection strings?

Next to [Roman's suggestion for Azure IoT Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73842459/8800237), you can also write your own SAS token generator. [The documentation you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-dev-guide-sas?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&tabs=csharp#sas-token-structure) also code samples in four programming languages; you can use those to create SAS tokens for a device as well. Use `{hub name}.azure-devices.net/devices/{device name}` for the `resourceUri` and don't include a `policyName`.

> Is there any way to generate per-device SAS tokens in Azure Portal?

No (I mean, you could use the Cloud Shell and use the Azure CLI in the Portal, but I don't think that's what you're asking). There is no visual interface for this in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Is there a way to generate SAS tokens for multiple devices at once?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Azure IoT Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-fundamentals/howto-use-iot-explorer).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help. Which one is of the two tools work better or is deprecated: "Azure IoT tools for Visual Studio Code" or "Azure IoT Explorer" ?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would generate the SAS token on the device, at least in a production environment due to the SAS token having a limited lifetime. Once that expires you would need to go back and give it a new one.
You don't mention what language you might be using but, if you are using C you will notice that the examples cited above do not include that language. I have a C demo here though: https://github.com/markrad/IoTSASTokenGenerate should it be of interest to you.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to generate SAS tokens in the Azure portal:

- In your IoT hub, navigate to **Devices** in the **Device Management** section.
- Either add a new device or select an existing one.
- You can view the SAS keys and connection strings for the device.
- The **Manage keys** menu lets you regenerate and swap keys.

[image]

Comment: I tried that. The connection string is not accepted by the REST calls when I add it to the "Authorization" header.

Comment: Those are not SAS tokens. The primary and secondary keys are just that: keys. They are used to generate the tokens. The keys are used in combination with the resource uri and expiry time to create the token. SAS tokens are there to avoid you sending these keys over the internet, these should never be shared!

Comment: That is correct. Those are not SAS tokens. They are connection strings that are used to generate SAS tokens.